$\aleph_1$ people in a row wearing black and white hats
The following is a well known riddle: countably many people stand in a line, each seeing everyone ahead of them, and each wearing a hat colored black or white. At some moment, they all guess their own hat color. Create a strategy so that all but finitely many of them guess correctly. The solution is to define equivalence classes on binary sequences using the relation of being eventually equal, and have everyone use the same choice function on these classes to guess the sequence they are in based on the all but finitely many hats they see, and guess accordingly. From some point on, everyone is correct. Note that this solution uses the axiom of choice to choose representatives.
I'm interested in longer lines of people, again wearing black and white hats. For example for $\omega_1$ people, using a similar strategy with the equivalence relation of being eventually equal, one can ensure only countably many people guess incorrectly.
My question is: for which ordinals $o$ is there a finite-error strategy for a line of legnth $o$?
To define things more precisely: the people in line know their own locations, so a strategy for $o$ people is a function $f : \{B, W\}^o \times o \to \{B, W\}$, where the first coordinate of the input is the line and the second is their own location. We want that for any $b \in \{B, W\}^o$, we have $f(b, \alpha) = b(\alpha)$ for cofinitely many $\alpha \in o$, as well as $f$ "ignoring" the first $\alpha$ elements of its input, meaning $f(b, \alpha) = f(c, \alpha)$ for all $b, c$ that are equal after $\alpha$.
Note that if the line is not well ordered, we can pick an infinite descending sequence of people and change their hat colors starting with the last one, ensuring they all guess wrong, so a finite-error strategy can only exist in well ordered lines. This also shows that any strategy must allow for arbitrarily (finitely) many mistakes.
Also, there is a finite error strategy for $\omega \cdot n$ people, as each copy of $\omega$ can ignore the rest and use the original strategy, so the hypothesis is true for $o < \omega ^ 2$.

There is a finite-error strategy for any ordinal $\omicron$!
Pick a well-order on the set of possible color assignments $\{B, W\}^\omicron$.
Suppose the actual coloring is $C \in \{B, W\}^\omicron$
Let $G_\alpha$ be the smallest coloring compatible with a suffix:
$$G_\alpha = \min \{g\in \{B, W\}^\omicron : g(\beta) = C(\beta) \text{ for } \beta\ge\alpha \}$$
$G$ is non-increasing and $G_0 = C$.
Contestant $\alpha$ will guess the smallest possible coloring based on what they see and announce their hat as matching that, i.e. $\alpha$ says $G_{\alpha+1}(\alpha)$.
If $\alpha$ guesses correctly then $G_{\alpha+1} = G_{\alpha}$. If they make a mistake then $G_{\alpha+1} < G_{\alpha}$.
If there is an infinite sequence of people who have made mistakes $\alpha_0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \ldots$ then $C > G_{\alpha_0+1} > G_{\alpha_1+1} > G_{\alpha_2+1} > \ldots$ is an infinite decreasing sequence of color assignments. But that's impossible because we have well-ordered them.
Therefore the number of mistakes is finite.
